# Can I use jQuery ajax in a SharePoint WebPart without having to worry about the same origin policy?

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, web-parts, same-origin-policy

My current project for work involves developing a SharePoint 2007 WebPart which will be deployed by our clients. To provide a better user experience, I am "simulating" ajax via setting the `SRC` attribute of an `IFRAME` to be the address of an HTTP handler. These handlers are deployed to the layouts directory in the 12 hive.

Although this works, I would prefer to use the `$get()` method of jQuery. Will this work reliably in my scenario or will I still be subject to the same origin policy? What about the scenario where the WebPart is being deployed to various places on a SharePoint farm? Will there be any problems with using `$get()` in that case?

Would the Same Origin Policy prevent me from invoking an HTTP handler using `$get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `ashx` handlers to the `12\TEMPLATE` folder you are adding the handlers to *all sites and sub-sites on your applications*.  Essentially, you have many copies of them.
If the AJAX call is relative to the domain, for example to `/_layouts/foo.ashx`, it will not be affected by the same origin policy.
Other scenarios, where the handlers are installed in a fixed location (e.g. Central Administration), will be blocked by the policy, same as every other page.

Comment: Thanks, Kobi, I wondered if this might have been the case. My AJAX calls are indeed relative.

Answer (score 0):

The browser implements the same origin policy in normal viewing mode no matter if you are running locally or remotely. The domains must match.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Yes, domain, port and protocol must match. What I really need to know is whether these three things will match if I am using $get to invoke an HTTP handler.